# Magento 500 internal server error

Tags: php, magento, cookies

I have a Magento site. The problem is when we browse the frontend after a few page visits suddenly the site stops loading. When I look into the server access log, it shows response code 500 for the URL which was accessed last. I am unable to reproduce the issue because the errorneous URL is not consistent.

If I would delete the cookie "frontend" set by Magento, the site works seamlessly again. I don't know how I can narrow down the debugging considering the effect of "frontend" cookie. Can anyone please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check var/log/exception.log and var/log/system.log to see if anything is popping up in there. Especially if there are exceptions being logged, there is a good chance those are causing the 500 status.

Comment: But not show any error in logs, it pops sometimes only. Deleting 'frontend' cookie fixes the site back.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file permission . it would be changed

Comment: Yes i checked all files but it pops sometimes only. Deleting 'frontend' cookie fixes the site back.